# Setting up interactive session in SLURM

Tags: slurm

I have a workstation with 256 (128x2) cores where I am submitting jobs using the SLURM scheduler. I am also trying to set up an interactive session where two cores are reserved for this using srun/salloc, but neither of these seem to be working properly. When they do work, they try to use both the sockets and will not be submitted properly if I have other jobs running. I will also not be able to submit any jobs while this interactive session is running with these commands even though there should be 254 available cores. Has anyone had a similar problem or know how to fix this? Thanks!

Edit: We are using kernel 6.2.0-26-generic and ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Comment: which Linux Distro/version are you using. Add to your question not in the comments